Are Subgroup-analyses in Metafor two-tailed?
this is probably a really obvious question, but I just want to make sure I interpret everything correctly. I am conducting a three-level meta-analysis on experimental studies in R using metafor, when looking at subgroup analyses (e.g., if the type of control group moderates the main effect of the manipulation), it employs a t-test. I have one-tailed/directed hypotheses (e.g., when experimental group is compared to control group A, the effect is larger than when experimental group is compared to control group B) so I could use a one-tailed test. I was wondering if the tests employed are two-tailed (and thus I could theoretically divide the p-value by half) or if only the test for the intercept is two-tailed (testing if it is different from zero, either higher or lower) but not the comparisons between intercept and other moderator levels or if neither are two-tailed.
Thank you in advance for any help!
Lea

If you are asking what metafor reports, then the answer is that the p-values are two-sided. Note that you can only divide the p-value by half if the direction of the observed effect matches your hypothesis.

Thank you, this was exactly what I was asking!
